# How to check if variable is empty using filter_input_array()?

Tags: php, validation, input

I am validating a form in which some fields must be in particular format, and some just have to be filled... So I use something like

```
        $trusty = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST , array(
            'status'=>array(
                'filter'=>FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                'options'=>array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 3, 'default'=>2)
            ),
            'tags'=>array(
                'filter'=>FILTER_CALLBACK,
                'options'=>function($value) {
                   if (mb_strpos($value, ",") === false) {
                       return trim($value);
                   } else {
                       $tags = explode(",", $value);
                       $tags = array_map(function($val) {
                           return trim($val);
                       }, $tags);
                       return $tags;
                   }
                },
            )   
        ));
```

to validate thoose which need particular format, but I also have fields 'title' and 'body' which can be anything but should not be empty. Of course I can check it separatly but I'd like to do all validation in one place. And my question is:
Is there a filter, or flag that checks if variable is empty?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
$trusty = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST , array(
        'status'=>array(
            'filter'=>FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
            'options'=>array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 3, 'default'=>2)
        ),
        'tags'=>array(
            'filter'=>FILTER_CALLBACK,
            'options'=>function($value) {
               if (mb_strpos($value, ",") === false) {
                   return trim($value);
               } else {
                   $tags = explode(",", $value);
                   $tags = array_map(function($val) {
                       return trim($val);
                   }, $tags);
                   return $tags;
               }
            },
        ) ,
        'title'=>array(
            'filter'=>FILTER_CALLBACK,
            'options'=>function($value) {
                return empty($value);
            }
        ) 
    ));
```

This should also work:

```
'title'=>array(
    'filter'=>FILTER_CALLBACK,
    'options'=>'empty'
)
```

Comment: yeah, that occurred to me too, but it looks... unnatural. Well, it looks like I'll have to roll with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in php to check empty variable

```
    empty ( mixed $var )
```

**You Can Have a Look:** [this](https://www.php.net/empty)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at all. The OP wants to know how to use filter_input_array() without accessing superglobal $_POST, $_GET, etc. arrays directly (which may be suggested).